# Magento Sort configurable option values

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have size option for all configurable products the problem here is that the values not sorted as needed, let me explain i've these values

```
array('XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL', 'XXXXL');
```

and the way it appear in the site is like this

```
array('XXXXL', 'XXXL', 'L', 'M', 'S', 'XL', 'XS', 'XXL', 'XXS');
```

in the back end the product with the associated products.

[image: I need the order to be like what's in box #2 but what i got in the size is what i have in box #1]

I need the order to be like what's in box #2 but what i got in the size is what i have in box #1

How could i do that and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem

what you can do is create module which extends

> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection

with this code

> ```
> /**
>  * Load attribute prices information
>  *
>  * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
>  */
> protected function _loadPrices()
> {
>     if ($this->count()) {
>         $pricings = array(
>             0 => array()
>         );
>
>         if ($this->getHelper()->isPriceGlobal()) {
>             $websiteId = 0;
>         } else {
>             $websiteId = (int)Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
>             $pricing[$websiteId] = array();
>         }
>
>         $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
>             ->from(array('price' => $this->_priceTable))
>             ->where('price.product_super_attribute_id IN (?)', array_keys($this->_items));
>
>         if ($websiteId > 0) {
>             $select->where('price.website_id IN(?)', array(0, $websiteId));
>         } else {
>             $select->where('price.website_id = ?', 0);
>         }
>
>         $query = $this->getConnection()->query($select);
>
>         while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
>             $pricings[(int)$row['website_id']][] = $row;
>         }
>
>         $values = array();
>
>         foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
>             $productAttribute = $item->getProductAttribute();
>             if (!($productAttribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)) {
>                 continue;
>             }
>             $options = $productAttribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();
>
>             $optionsByValue = array();
>             foreach ($options as $option) {
>                 $optionsByValue[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
>             }
>
>             foreach ($this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
>                          ->getUsedProducts(array($productAttribute->getAttributeCode()), $this->getProduct())
>                      as $associatedProduct) {
>
>                 $optionValue = $associatedProduct->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
>
>                 if (array_key_exists($optionValue, $optionsByValue)) {
>                     // If option available in associated product
>                     if (!isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue])) {
>                         // If option not added, we will add it.
>                         $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $optionValue] = array(
>                             'product_super_attribute_id' => $item->getId(),
>                             'value_index'                => $optionValue,
>                             'label'                      => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
>                             'default_label'              => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
>                             'store_label'                => $optionsByValue[$optionValue],
>                             'is_percent'                 => 0,
>                             'pricing_value'              => null,
>                             'use_default_value'          => true
>                         );
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         foreach ($pricings[0] as $pricing) {
>             // Addding pricing to options
>             $valueKey = $pricing['product_super_attribute_id'] . ':' . $pricing['value_index'];
>             if (isset($values[$valueKey])) {
>                 $values[$valueKey]['pricing_value']     = $pricing['pricing_value'];
>                 $values[$valueKey]['is_percent']        = $pricing['is_percent'];
>                 $values[$valueKey]['value_id']          = $pricing['value_id'];
>                 $values[$valueKey]['use_default_value'] = true;
>             }
>         }
>
>         if ($websiteId && isset($pricings[$websiteId])) {
>             foreach ($pricings[$websiteId] as $pricing) {
>                 $valueKey = $pricing['product_super_attribute_id'] . ':' . $pricing['value_index'];
>                 if (isset($values[$valueKey])) {
>                     $values[$valueKey]['pricing_value']     = $pricing['pricing_value'];
>                     $values[$valueKey]['is_percent']        = $pricing['is_percent'];
>                     $values[$valueKey]['value_id']          = $pricing['value_id'];
>                     $values[$valueKey]['use_default_value'] = false;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Mage 1.9+ fix for configurable attribute options not sorting to position
>          * @author Harshit <support@cubixws.co.uk>
>          */
>          $sortOrder = 1;
>          foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
>             $productAttribute = $item->getProductAttribute();
>             if (!($productAttribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract)) {
>                 continue;
>             }
>             $options = $productAttribute->getFrontend()->getSelectOptions();
>             foreach ($options as $option) {
>                 if (!$option['value']) continue;
>                 if (isset($values[$item->getId() . ':' . $option['value']])) {
>                     $values[$item->getId() . ':' . $option['value']]['order'] = $sortOrder++;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         usort($values, function($a, $b) {
>             return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
>         });
>         foreach ($values as $data) {
>             $this->getItemById($data['product_super_attribute_id'])->addPrice($data);
>         }
>     }
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

Comment: i solve this issue with another way, let me tell you about it, when i add the size values like XL and XS etc i erase them and re add them with the order i need like starting from XXS ending with XXXXL or 4XL and it work very fine with me

Answer (score 0):

> i solve this issue with another way, let me tell you about it, when i add the size values like XL and XS etc i erase them and re add them with the order i need like starting from XXS ending with XXXXL or 4XL and it work very fine with me